# Does the code take constant space in memory for any given input?

Tags: java, string, memory

```
public static String switchString(String word, int i, int j) {
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
    newString.append(word.substring(j, word.length()));
    newString.append(word.substring(i + 1, j));
    newString.append(word.substring(0, i + 1));
    return newString.toString();
}
```

For a given input `String` and indexes `i` and `j`, the code should do something like this: if `word = “abcdef”` and `i = 1`, `j = 3`. Output should be: “defcab”.

Assuming that the word is not `null` and `i` and `j` are not out of bounds, the code works fine. I want to know if, for a string of any given length, does this program take constant space in memory via this approach.

Comment: Not sure what you expect it to do but i think you get a `OutOfRange` exception or someting like this at `newString.append(word.substring(j, word.length()));`

Comment: Assuming that the word is not null and i and j are not index that are out of bound, the code works fine. I wanted to know if for a string of any given length, does it take a constant space is memory via this approach.

Comment: Keywords: "given length". This would mean that your program is going to take some factor of `n` memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `String`s are immutable. Calling `substring` makes a new `String`.

If your `String word` is some length `n`, you end up generating substrings with a total length of `n`.

Whatever the size of `StringBuilder` is is constant. Whatever metadata is stored in each `String` is also constant. What changes is the length of the string.

Thus, **no, this approach does not use constant space, but `n` space.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know an approach with which I could solve this problem with constant space?

Comment: If you are trying to do it with variable-length strings, constant space is infeasible. The way Java works would prevent you from working on the `String word` you pass without making a copy, also.